# how to tell if somebody has accessed your machine with dameware?

Tags: security, windows-7, remote, remote-desktop

I understand anybody with local admin or domain admin can dameware into your client and see your screen as you are working. Is this true?

How can I tell who's recently accessed my machine this way?
Is there evidence in any of the event logs?
Any way to stop it?
How add more logging to my windows 7 client?

Thanks.

Comment: If your IT admin has put DameWare on your machine and you're worried they're watching, then you should either a) check your employment contract, or b) start working!  It's their machine to monitor.  Either way, this isn't a question for StackOverflow.

Comment: @Cyberpine, you really need to clarify your question by telling us if this is your home PC or a PC in a business environment that you don't own, otherwise this topic may be closed.